# How to add some configuration option to vertical tab on content type edit page

Tags: nodes, entities

Is it possible without touching Dupal core's code, add some configuration option to content type edit page? preferably to vertical tabs of bottom? such as a checkbox.

I mean this page: /admin/structure/types/manage/article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add a fieldset to the content type edit form with [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7).

e.g:

```
function MYMODULE_form_node_type_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // Define field set in additional settings group
    $form['advanced'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Advanced settings'),
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed' => TRUE,
      '#weight' => 10,
      '#group' => 'additional_settings',
    );
    // Add checkbox option
    $form['advanced']['special_option'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Use special option'),
    );
    // Set default value from automatically saved config variable
    $form['advanced']['special_option']['#default_value'] = variable_get('special_option_' . $form['#node']->type, 1);

}
```

Comment: I must be missing something, but my custom advanced option is not saved automatically in the {variable} table... Maybe I must implement some other hooks to save the custom option?

Comment: I think `$form['#node_type']->type` is more `$form['#node']->type`or `$form['type']['#value']` or `$form['#bundle']`...

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer: seems to be needed to add a submit function to your $form, to set the variable to store.

In the MYMODULE_form_node_form_alter() function, add:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_node_form_submit';
```

then the submit function:

```
function userprog_node_form_submit ($form, &$form_state) {
  $special = $form_state['values']['special_option'];

  variable_set('MYMODULE_' . $form_state['values']['type'] . '_special_option', $special);
}
```

NB: the variable_get() in the hook_form_alter() function, becomes:

```
// Set default value from automatically saved config variable
$form['advanced']['special_option']['#default_value'] = variable_get('MYMODULE_' . $form['#node_type']->type . '_special_option', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at the nodeapi_example module. (From the Drupal Example modules).

It gives a quite legible example on adding a setting to the *content type edit page* AND an extra 'setting'/option to every node for which it is enabled.